# How to show a bar chart by command in the pysimplegui?

Tags: python, dataframe, bar-chart, spyder, pysimplegui

i got my pysimplegui work normally, and then i wanted to add the bar chart to the pysimplegui, but the only thing that appear is the coordinate and the text of the bar chart, the bar chart itself is being printed on the python console. figure 1, [the code to call the pysimplegui and the bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53HIR.png).
figure 2, [it appears like that in the popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoLiO.png).
figure 3, [and it ends up showing the graph in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIdWx.png)

i want to make the bar chart appear on the figure 2, can anybody help me?

Comment: No picture only, short and executable code in code format, then your expectation.

Comment: so the bar chart wont appear on the pop up window?

Comment: You should use a second window, with a second layout.  The popup is limited to text.

Comment: It looks like you need to look at the demo programs for the matplotlib examples. They show how to embed the graphs so they don't show up in a second window.

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up only allows for text, you are going to need two windows to do this, here is an example with two windows.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
"""
    Demo - 2 simultaneous windows using read_all_window

    Both windows are immediately visible.  Each window updates the other.

    Copyright 2020 PySimpleGUI.org
"""

def make_win1():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Window 1')],
              [sg.Text('Enter something to output to Window 2')],
              [sg.Input(key='-IN-', enable_events=True)],
              [sg.Text(size=(25,1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
              [sg.Button('Reopen')],
              [sg.Button('Exit')]]
    return sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True)


def make_win2():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Window 2')],
              [sg.Text('Enter something to output to Window 1')],
              [sg.Input(key='-IN-', enable_events=True)],
              [sg.Text(size=(25,1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
              [sg.Button('Exit')]]
    return sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True)


def main():
    window1, window2 = make_win1(), make_win2()

    window2.move(window1.current_location()[0], window1.current_location()[1]+220)

    while True:             # Event Loop
        window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()

        if window == sg.WIN_CLOSED:     # if all windows were closed
            break
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            window.close()
            if window == window2:       # if closing win 2, mark as closed
                window2 = None
            elif window == window1:     # if closing win 1, mark as closed
                window1 = None
        elif event == 'Reopen':
            if not window2:
                window2 = make_win2()
                window2.move(window1.current_location()[0], window1.current_location()[1] + 220)
        elif event == '-IN-':
            output_window = window2 if window == window1 else window1
            if output_window:           # if a valid window, then output to it
                output_window['-OUTPUT-'].update(values['-IN-'])
            else:
                window['-OUTPUT-'].update('Other window is closed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```